# Round robin probability question

Tags: probability

Lets say there are $n$ players playing in a round robin tournament and they have to each play against another player exactly once.

1) How many outcomes are there for the tournament? (Outcome lists out who won and who lost for each game)

2) How many games are played in total?

What would be the correct way to approach this question? I have seen answers saying it is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ games and each game has 2 outcomes so there are $2^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$. How are these answers reached?

Answer (score 1):

Each player plays $n-1$ games. There are $n$ players. Each game has $2$ players playing.

Comment: Hi, I edit my question a bit, what about the $2^\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ part? why is it 2 to the power of?

Answer (score 0):

I think Alexander gives the best argument for why there are $\frac{n/n-1)}{2}$ games.

Another argument is that the number of possible games is equal to the choices for player $1$ and player $2$ in match (since we have every possible matchup in the tournament exactly once). There are $n$ choices for player $1$ and $n-1$ choices for player $2$. Of course if we do this every game is counted twice since we count the match between players $a$ and $b$ once when $a$ is player $1$ and $b$ is player $2$ and a second time when $b$ is player $1$ and $a$ is player $2$. This tells us there are $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$ games played.

As to why the tournament can have $2^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$ outcomes, notice that for every match there are two possible outcomes.